# PrimeFaces datatable Scrollbar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, css

I have a form with a primefaces datatable which i have set the columns width in css for it :

```
.idcol{width: 5%}
.prioritycol{width: 5%}
.titlecol{width: 30%}
.descriptioncol{width: 40%}
.actionscol{width: 10px}
```

Everything is okay but when i add the `scrollable="true"` attribute in order to have a scrollable datatable, the result is worst :

[image]

This is the declaration of the datatable :

```
<p:dataTable  id="dtable" var="todos" value="#{todo.todoList}" scrollable="true" 
                             resizableColumns="false" scrollHeight="300" lazy="true"
                             styleClass="idcol,prioritycol,titlecol,descriptioncol,actionscol">
```

What is the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: without scrollable it's working fine?

Comment: How does it sees (paste screen shot) when scrollable="true" is set ?

Comment: You set: <p:column width="300"> it will work fine.

Comment: @Ravi yes it works fine when i set scrollable="false"!

Comment: @RodmarConde the screenshot is after adding the scrollable="true" attribute

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I found the solution,
You have to edit you css and you JSF code at the same time and looking what you have as result,
For my problem i edited my css and the jsf code step by step, here is the code that worked for me :

CSS :

```
.idcol{width: 5%}
.prioritycol{width: 5%}
.titlecol{width: 30%}
.descriptioncol{width: 40%}
.actionscol{width: 20%}
```

The Form :

> 1. Column 1 : width="25"
> 2. Column 2 : width="55"
> 3. Column 3 : width="369"
> 4. Column 4 : width="469"
> 5. Column 5 : width="170"

Comment: I don't understand ur solution: Do you mean you have set different widths values in one column, like: 
`<p: styleClass="idcol" width="25">`. Can you please post your xhtml-code.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the column width this way

```
<p:column headerText="Type"  width="70%">
```

or you can specify style class this way

```
<p:column headerText="Type"  styleClass="idcol"  >
```

You can add  scrollWidth some thing like this

```
<p:dataTable var="data"  rowKey="#{data.key}" style="width:70%" 
sortOrder="ascending"
selection=""
value=""
selectionMode="single"
scrollable="true" 
scrollWidth="71%" 
scrollHeight="3%"
>

<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener=""
update="" />

<p:column headerText="Type"  styleClass=""  sortBy="" width="70%">
<h:outputText id="dataTYpe" value="" />
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Category"  sortBy="" width="30%">
<h:outputText value="" />
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```